# How can I modify the value of a private field in bean from a dependency jar?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to change the value of a private field in bean without modifying the spring project code apparent logic but just by adding a dependency that I developed. More details at below:

**More Details**

What I can only modify in this spring project is its pom.xml where I would add my own dependency as below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.task.is</groupId>
    <artifactId>modify-spring-bean-private-field-value</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The Spring bean looks like below and I'd like to modify its value in my added dependency.

```
// no touch for anything in this class in spring project
@Configuration
public class InSpringProjectConfig {  
    @Value(${some.value.in.spring.project.config.file.that.I.would.not.touch})
    private String changeMe;  // no Setter for this field in this class
    ..
}
```

**What I tried**

- Reflection

I tried reflection to get the InSpringProjectConfig bean's fields by using getFields and getDeclaredFields, but all the fields are with the name prefixed like CGLIB$ and no one has the similar name as *changeMe*.

- AspectJ

Theoretically, the AspectJ should have solution to access this field and modify its value outside the project, but as I've already used spring-aop in this dependency, the AspectJ seems conflict with it and make the spring-aop code non-functional. I'll consider using 100% AspectJ as my last choice.

- Spring Bean Creation hooks

This seems to need to modify the *InSpringProjectConfig* class in the spring project.

- Replace the bean

I'd still like to just modify the private field in bean rather than replace the whole bean.

Comment: you can't although you can update the values using a conrtructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a solution from baeldung.com, big thank you to Eugen who emailed me this solution, I paste it as below.

---

Roughly speaking, you should follow these steps:

1- Create a class implementing the EnvironmentPostProcessor interface, adding a PropertySource to the Spring Environment with precedence over the other property sources your application uses. Of course, you can define your own mechanism to setup this PropertySource, but a simple implementation can look like this:

```
public class MyCustomEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        Map<String, Object> myProperties =
            Collections.singletonMap("some.value.in.spring.project.config.file.that.I.would.not.touch", "changed-value");

        environment.getPropertySources()
            .addFirst(new MapPropertySource("myProps", myProperties));
    }
}
```

2- Then you can add the following entry to the META-INF/spring.factories file in your library:

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.baeldung.mylibrary.spring.MyCustomEnvironmentPostProcessor
```

And that's it, now your application will inject the value of this custom property source, since it has a higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

`@Value` annotation can be used for injecting values into fields in Spring-managed beans, and it can be applied at the field or constructor/method parameter level. Click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation#usage-examples) for more info.

```java
@Value(${some.value.in.spring.project.config.file.that.I.would.not.touch})
private String changeMe;
```

Since it is a Spring-managed bean and there is no `Setter` & the property is `private`, the only way to alter the value is by changing in `properties` file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I do not totally agree with "changing in properties file" is the only way of archiving this. I think Java has the ability to change any field for any object in JVM, no matter if the Setter exists or what access level modifier they got. I'm thinking of using the java agent instead of a dependency to achieve this if the reflection and spring cannot offer any mechanism to do so.